# Translate Menu Mobily

Tags: image, magento, mobile, translate

I need to translate the menu title on mobile.

Meeting I could not find the file.

You can send me the path and file name I thank you.

I'm sending an image.

Much Peace, gratitude.

[translate menu mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unR1A.jpg)

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad for SO to answer. You may want to look up how to create Translations within the Magento documentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?